# Why $\delta F = B\epsilon$ and not $F=B \epsilon$ in supersymmetry?

Tags: supersymmetry, fermions, bosons, grassmann-numbers, superalgebra

We can express supersymmetric transformations as
$$\delta F = B\epsilon, \tag{1} $$
$$\delta B = F\bar{\epsilon},\tag{2}$$
where $B$ and $F$ denote the bosons and fermions, respectively, in the theory and  is
the local supersymmetry parameter.

My question could be silly, but if the phrase in **bold** above says that and doesn't instead say the ***variation*** of fermions must transform into bosons and vice versa why doesn't (1) look like $$F=\epsilon B.$$ Where did the "$\delta$" in $\delta F$ in (1) come from?

Comment: There is one simple way to see why $F=\epsilon B$ is not allowed. Here $\epsilon$ is a parameter of symmetry transformation. So we can choose the value of $\epsilon$ whatever we want. If you choose $\epsilon=0$, you get $F=0,B=0$. This gives you a theory with nothing, no bosons and no fermions. But we desire to have a non-trivial theory whatever the value of $\epsilon$ is and this means that you cannot have the relations like $F=\epsilon B$.

Comment: Would this mean that the famous sentencing above is wrong or at least not precise? Again the sentence sentence says that the wording of (1) and (2) is that the fermions in the theory transform into some bosonic conguration and similarly the bosons transform into some fermionic conguration. Note that this is used in hundreds of papers and books as you might know. @Minkyoto

Comment: No, the paragraph above the question is right. But I guess I can't understand your question correctly. Can you rephrase your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're just not parsing the sentence correctly, or rather, you're just being too nitpicky. When one says that supersymmetry *"transforms bosons into fermions and vice versa"*, one means that, under an *infinitesimal transformation*, the variation is purely fermionic for bosons, i.e.
$$ B\mapsto B+\delta B = B+\epsilon F$$
for some bosonic $B$ and some fermionic $F$.

Supersymmetry is meant to be a *smooth transformation*, i.e. one can integrate this to a finite supersymmetry transformation, just like one integrate the infinitesimal rotation $\vec v \mapsto v + \epsilon L_i \vec v$ to $\vec v \mapsto \mathrm{e}^{\epsilon L_i}\vec v$. For your proposed $B\mapsto \epsilon F$, you *cannot* expand the r.h.s. in powers of epsilon to get back an infinitesimal transformation of the form $B+\delta B$, this already shows it's a "bad" transformation law.

Comment: do you by any chance know why the $\epsilon$ in (2) has a bar over it meanwhile the one in (1) doesn't?

Comment: @Beyond-formulas: Because it is a spinor, and $\bar \epsilon$ is its conjugate spinor.

Comment: Yes, this I know. I meant why would one be without a bar and the other with a bar?

Comment: @Beyond-formulas: ...because the transformation is not a symmetry if you take both to be $\epsilon$ or both to be $\bar\epsilon$? You only get a symmetry transformation if you choose one to be $\epsilon$ and the other to be $\bar\epsilon$. For instance $F\epsilon$ would not be bosonic, it's not even defined, but the contraction of the spinor $F$ with a conjugate spinor $\bar\epsilon$ is well-defined, and is a scalar, i.e. bosonic.

Comment: @ACuriousMind I have a question. When we say the theory is invariant under this supersymmetric transformation e.g. (1), then $\delta F=0$, no? What does this mean physically? Does it mean that fermions stay fermions? Because as you know when we're seeking supersymmetric solutions, we tend to look for an $\epsilon$ such that the susy transformation vanish.

Comment: @Fluctuations: no, invariance means $\delta L = 0$ for the Lagrangian without use of the e. o. m. And the variation of any solution under *any* transformation vanishes - that's precisely the condition of being a solution to the EL equations.

Comment: [Here] (https://books.google.com.lb/books?id=KFUhAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA249&lpg=PA249&dq=van+proeyen+freedman+supergravity+It+is+most+useful+to+obtain+solutions+that+can+be+interpreted+as+backgrounds+or+vacua.&source=bl&ots=vh-QrPO7je&sig=ZDggO4dPDDVcNeiqaC8ojY8clSQ&hl=ar&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjUzdDYj__JAhXG1BoKHaqyBX0Q6AEIGjAA#v=onepage&q=van%20proeyen%20freedman%20supergravity%20It%20is%20most%20useful%20to%20obtain%20solutions%20that%20can%20be%20interpreted%20as%20backgrounds%20or%20vacua.&f=false), it says: _For a preserved supersymmetry, the local SUSY variations of all fields must vanish_ (see 12.15)

Comment: Given the link I attached above, this sets what I claimed as true that $\delta F=0$ for a preserved supersymmetric theory. Thus my question was what does $\delta F=0$ imply?Does it mean that fermions stay fermions? Because it would be weird if it means so, no? :S

Comment: @Fluctuations: You're completely misunderstanding what a "preserved supersymmetry" is. That's not a requirement *on the theory*, it is just a requirement on the *classical solutions*, that they be mapped onto themselves under the *preserved* supersymmetric transformation (i.e. $\delta X = 0$ for all fields), and not onto another solution (this is just a weird way of stating that the solution doesn't break the supersymmetry). If you have a question about that, please ask it seperately, because this has nothing to do with my answer or this question.

Comment: @ACuriousMind I have posted a question there as I was confused about $\delta X=0$ and what you said abou classical solutions... that you wrote up here. Would appreciate if you take a look at the question http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/226391/what-does-%ce%b4f-0-imply .. indeed looks I am completely misunderstanding this :s

Answer (score 1):

The $\epsilon$ parametrizes the amount of symmetry transformation. Suppose you don't want any symmetry transformation in the field configuration. So what we want to do is to take the field congiguration and take it to itself. This is the case when $\epsilon = 0.$ So going by your definition, we will get $F = 0$ and conversely $B = 0$, which is not correct. Whereas taking $\delta F = 0$ gives us back the same field configuration that we started with.

Note : The formulas you have written are strictly not correct as we also require auxillary fields so as to perform a symmetry invariant lagrangian off-shell.