# contraction of the spinor F with a conjugate spino $\bar{\epsilon}$ is bosonic?

Tags: supersymmetry

In this [Why $\delta F = B\epsilon$ and not $F=B \epsilon$ in supersymmetry?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/226257/why-delta-f-b-epsilon-and-not-f-b-epsilon-in-supersymmetry), I asked ACuriousMind why would one epsilon be without a bar and the other with a bar here:
$$\delta F = B\epsilon, \tag{1} $$
$$\delta B = F\bar{\epsilon},\tag{2}$$
I got the answer which was very satisfying at the moment

> because the transformation is not a symmetry if you take both to be $ϵ$ or both to be $\bar{ϵ}$? You only get a symmetry transformation if you choose one to be $ϵ$ and the other to be $\bar{ϵ}$. **For instance $Fϵ$ would not be bosonic, it's not even defined, but the contraction of the spinor $F$ with a conjugate spinor $\bar{ϵ}$ is well-defined, and is a scalar**, i.e. bosonic.

However, as  am rereading this I guess I need more details to understand this, specifically ... the bold part above.

Comment: Do you know about spinor i.e. SU(2) indices? If so, put them in your formulas (1) and (2).

Comment: I don't understand what you said. Can you elaborate your answer? @HansMoleman

Comment: Sorry, but if you don't know what Weyl fermions and SU(2) indices etc. are you will obviously not understand the SUSY algebra. This is all textbook material and it would take a long time to explain. My best advice for you is to very carefully study pages 4-20 of Terning - Modern Supersymmetry (Oxford 2006).

Comment: @HansMoleman my question is simpler than that, I was asking, what does ACuriousMind mean matematically when he said: "the contraction of the spinor F with a conjugate spinor$\bar{\epsilon}$ is well-defined..." I am having problems with notation not the concept.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to transform $F \epsilon$ under Lorentz transformations. You will notice that it does not transform like a Lorenz invariant bosonic quantity, i.e. vector, scalar, rank-2 tensor,... You have to have $\bar\epsilon F$ to correspond to a bosonic quantity.

Comment: You have stated the same thing as the comment I quoted up there in my question. I was looking more into mathematical details of how this wouldn't transform under a bosonic quantity unless there is a bar on the epsilon.

Comment: you can check the lecture notes on QFT by David Tong, page 88. There he explains what fermionic bilinear transforms as bosonic quantity.

Comment: Can you explain this a little bit more. I am talking about the epsilon and the bar on the epsilon. Those are Tong's lecture notes: http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/qft/qft.pdf but I don't understand what is it that is related to my question?

Comment: Maybe for example what does ACuriousMind mean matematically when he said: "the contraction of the spinor F with a conjugate spinor$\bar{\epsilon}$ is well-defined..."